# Can we change the default VLAN of softlayer bare metal after its created?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create Baremetal using SoftLayer_Hardware's `CreateObject()` method in softlayer.

After creation, I want to change the default VLANs of the bare metal.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know it isn't possible, I recommend you to specify the vlans when creating the hardware server next time, use the parameters `primaryNetworkComponent.networkVlan.id` and `primaryBackendNetworkComponent.networkVlan.id` to set the vlans.

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/createObject/

You can also try by opening a ticket in SL, maybe the employees can help you to change the vlans.